# Как после определенного количества вызовов функций, обнулить значение когда нужно?

Tags: javascript

Нужно, чтобы у переменной обнулялось значение при повторном нажатии. В приложении при повторном нажатии вызова, таймер работает правильно, а прогресс бар, начинает движение с прошлого значения!

Чтобы запустить приложение: в кругу ставите ползунок на 1. И выше ползунка кнопка. Нажимаете первый раз все нормально, при втором нажатии,таймер работает заново, а прогресс бар начинает двигаться как двигался при прошлом значении.

Пример [тут](https://codepen.io/SeQwerMan/pen/jBMaRK)

```
function go_work(){
  if(interest != 60){
    interest++;
    document.getElementById('progress_bar').style.width = interest * 10+'px';
  }
}
```

```js
var interest = 0;
var flag = 1;

function go_work() {
  if (interest != 60) {
    interest++;
    document.getElementById('progress_bar').style.width = interest * 10 + 'px';
  }
}

function go_relax() {

}

function getvalue_relax() {
  var value = document.getElementById("relax_range").value;
  var value_com = value * 1000;
  return value_com;
}

function getvalue() {
  var value = document.getElementById("relax_work").value;
  var value_com = value * 1000;
  return value_com;
}

function timer(getvalue) {
  var time = getvalue;
  var time_query = Math.round(time / 1000);
  var min = time_query;
  var sec = document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML;
  return function() {
    if (sec > 0) sec--;
    else {
      sec = 60;
      if (min > 0) min--;
      else {
        sec = 0;
        go_relax();
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = min;
    document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = sec;
  }
}

$('#btn_pomod').click(function() {
  if (flag == 1) {
    document.getElementById('relax_work').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('relax_range').disabled = true;
    play = setInterval(go_work, getvalue());
    intervalID = setInterval(timer(getvalue()), 1000);
    var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
    var playing = document.createElement('div')
    playing.id = 'progress_bar';
    progress.appendChild(playing);
    flag = 0;
  } else if (flag == 0) {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    clearInterval(play);
    document.getElementById('relax_work').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('relax_range').disabled = false;
    document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('progress_bar').remove();

    flag = 1;
  }
})
```

Comment: весь **необходимый** код должен быть в вопросе. В примере по ссылке - непонятно куда надо нажимать, чтобы воспроизвести проблему. Выкинь все лишнее из примера и оставь только [mcve]